# Websockets and puma cluster mode

Tags: websocket, puma

I've build a small rack aap that implements a websocket and a plain http api endpoint, clients can connect to it and at a later point I can send a http post with a token and a client connected to the websocket will no notified.

My question is if puma is running in cluster mode with 4 workers is it possible that one worker holds the websocket connection and another is parsing the http request?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up implementing a solution based on redis from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-websockets